# StackOverflow Error when implementinf DoublyLinkedList

Tags: java, kotlin, doubly-linked-list

I am implementing doubly linked list using kotlin. But I am getting StackOverflow Error

**Main**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val doublyLinkedList = DoublyLinkedList()
doublyLinkedList.push(5)
doublyLinkedList.push(6)
doublyLinkedList.push(7)
doublyLinkedList.push(8)
doublyLinkedList.push(9)
println(doublyLinkedList.headNode)
```

}

**DoublyLinkedList**

```
class DoublyLinkedList {
var headNode: DNode? = null
var tailNode: DNode? = null
var length: Int = 0

fun isEmpty(): Boolean = length == 0

fun push(value:Any) {
    val newNode = DNode(value =value )
    if (isEmpty()){
        tailNode = newNode
    }else{
        headNode?.prevNode = newNode
    }
    newNode.nextNode = headNode
    headNode = newNode
    length++
}
```

}

**DataClass**

```
data class DNode(var value: Any,
             var prevNode: DNode? = null,
             var nextNode: DNode? = null)
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:449)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
at ds.doublyLinkedList.DNode.toString(DNode.kt)
```

after 1st element push it is showing *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError*. Why this is happening any ideas.

Comment: It's your `toString` that's throwing that exception

Comment: The exception is in `toString`, and you haven't shown us the code for that. Ideally, provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Jon Skeet  Updated with an example.

Comment: I don't know Kotlin, but it looks like you're probably currently using the default implementation of `toString()`, which will recurse forever as it ping-pongs between previous and next nodes. You'll need to override `toString()` in `DNode`.

Comment: So Instead of Data class I tried with simple class without Overriding and problem solved. I think some issue when using DataClass in kotlin.

Comment: It's not a data class problem.  (Note: in languages like Kotlin, where case and spacing matter, calling it ‘DataClass’ is confusing because it looks like the name of a particular class.)  It's just that the autogenerated `toString()` method can't handle object graphs with loops.  As Jon says, you could override it and write your own — that could help with debugging &c.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**

Instead of using DataClass I used class. Because in Kotlin data class the compiler automatically derives the following members from all properties declared in the primary constructor:

- equals()/hashCode() pair;
- toString() of the form "User(name=John,age=42)";
- componentN() functions corresponding to the properties in their order of declaration;
- copy() function